# How to delete apk/app from system/app via adb

Tags: adb

Hi guys ım trying to delete system apps which developed by custom user, not stock. Some app setted as a system apps. When ı try to delete, its saying not installed for user 0. How can ı solve this issue?
Also one times it said uninstall success but ı can still see the apk in system/apps.

Answer (score 0):

when ı remove apk from system / app wtih rm system/app/apk its solved